# Microsoft Access report shows empty row at the end

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an Access report. The problem is that it always display an empty row at the end. In the query there are no empty values however the report always shows an empty row. Any ideas?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5XFoGik1WSWUmRkRktla2VIYnM/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5XFoGik1WSWcFF3SnZpekVwTlU/view?usp=sharing

On a form I would set "Allow additions" to false. However I don't know what I would do on a report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A report has an OnNoData event that you could use to cancel the opening of the report. It is often used to popup a message with like "The report, with the specified parameters, would return no data." The code would popup the message, then run a DoCmd.Cancel, or Me.Close acReport, Me.Name.

You can also base the report on a query that has the AllowUpdates set to false (in the QBE, set the properties). Another idea would be to render the report in Preview Mode.